# Infinite Scroll triggred multiple times

Tags: angular, ionic2, infinite-scroll

I make an app based on ionic 2 that use the Infinite Scroll.

I got a little problem.. The event triggred multiple times that make my app not working well

Here's the code on the component for Infinite scroll

```
doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
  this.page += 1;

    this.loadPosts(this.page,"infinite");

  console.log(this.page);
  infiniteScroll.complete();
}
```

and this `console.log(this.page)` give me a 7. Why it jump to 7 ? not to the 2 first ?

It's weird, It' like multiple times triggred, so the `this.page` keep going up till the service load the data..

Here's the HTML Code

```
<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
        loadingSpinner="bubbles"
        loadingText="Loading more data...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Comment: You should use a debounce function

Comment: Any example @Chrillewoodz ? :)

Comment: Why do you need the timeout? Using timeouts in a service gives horrible results usually so I try to avoid it best I can

Comment: Alright, I will edit it... So, how about the multiple times triggered event ??

Comment: I can't find `debounce` function on ionic 2 for infinite scroll, can you give me an example how to use it @Chrillewoodz??

Comment: I'm not sure on how to apply it in your case since you just pass the function that is called :/

Comment: but, is that multiple trigger problem is possible to happen on my code ?? @Chrillewoodz

Comment: It sounds as if things runs too fast, and things run again before the previous action was finished.

Comment: ok, so how can I do that ? :D I don't have any clue :D @Chrillewoodz

Comment: Me neither tbh, sorry lol.

Comment: Oh no xD.. Oh yeah, is that something like bug from ionic  2?? Because I've seen something like this before and it works well, but it runs at ionic 1

Comment: Never used ionic so not sure.

Comment: can you see this ? the function triggered 12 times more than it should.. It's not make sense.. http://imgur.com/a/SXX4U